# Making a field Readonly in Lightning Related Record component doesn't lock field from editing

Tags: relatedrecord

I've got the following relationship

- SBQQ__Quote__c

  - SBAA__Approval__c

On **SBAA__Approval__c** I need to show information from **SBQQ__Quote__c** record.

Found that "Related Record" should work for me. I did the following:

- I've added "Related Record" component to flexipage in Lightning App Builder
  [image]
- Setup "Type" field on Update Action's layout to be "Read-Only"
  [image]

But whenever I open SBAA__Approval__c and view "Related Record" component - it allows me to edit "Type" field
[image]

How to make a field to be Read-Only on "Related Record" layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing "Edit Read-Only Fields" should help https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000335725&type=1